# Is there a way to add multiple validations in one Assertion in JMeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, assertion, web-api-testing

I want to add an assertion(e.g. Response Assertion, JSON Assertion..etc) to verify several inter-related values which return in a response (e.g. invalid status code, invalid status message) Without adding two assertions, can we verify multiples in one single assertion in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible with [`JSON Assertion`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion), But you can definitely add multiple asserts using [`Response Assertion`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) in following way :

[image: Multiple assertion]

You can add as many assertions as want, the catch is its always be on same `Field to Test`. Example: you cannot test response headers and response message in one assertion

Comment: This is teh Response header I'm getting HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Then I added pattern as "401 Unauthorized" but teh assertion result display as below...........Response Assertion : Test failed: code expected to match /200/ Response Assertion : Response was null What's wrong here?

Comment: @Flashmark: this is a different question than waht you asked, none the less you can solve that as using `Response Assertion`. You have to check the `Ignore Status` checkbox.  If response code is not in range of 2xx, by default JMeter mark that request as a failure, If you are expecting something else then you can use above checkbox

Answer (score 0):

If you have several validations which cannot be handled by a single assertion and you don't want to have multiple assertions the only choice is going for [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) where you can define whatever pass/fail criteria you want in [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/)

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial), a code example from it:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def failureMessage = "";
def jsonResponse = null;

JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper();

try {
    jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    failureMessage += "Invalid JSON.\n"
}

if (!"200".equals(prev.getResponseCode())) {
    failureMessage += "Expected <response code> [200] but we got instead [" + prev.getResponseCode() + "]\n\n";
}

if (!jsonResponse.keySet().containsAll(["api_version", "error", "result"])) {
    failureMessage += "The json config element has wrong structure.\n\n";
}

if (!jsonResponse.result.numberOfExpectedServers != 3) {
    failureMessage += "The element has wrong number of servers. Number of servers is:[" + jsonResponse.result.numberOfExpectedServers + "]\n\n";
}

if (failureMessage?.trim()) {
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}

// Print error messages if any
if (failureMessage?.trim()) {
    failureMessage += "URL: " + SampleResult.getURL() + "\n\n";
    failureMessage += "JSON RESPONSE: " + jsonResponse + "\n\n";
    failureMessage += "REQUEST HEADERS: " + SampleResult.getRequestHeaders() + "\n\n";

    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}
```